# Is it possible to add a tex-file for a "front page" in the YAML in Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I have created a general front page for my report in Overleaf, and have extracted this as a tex-file. I am wondering if I can just insert this tex-file in the YAML, instead of specifying a titlte, author etc. in the YAML.

Comment: Did you try the `includes`option? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#includes

Comment: Yes. I went for a template instead, where the frontpage is included. I use the command template: name_of_file.tex, but get the following error message:

! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

Next, I went to Options and Enabled shell escape commands, which did not help.